# Cannot open '/proc/.../maps': No such file or directory in radare2 debug mode

Tags: linux, radare2, debuggers

When I try to load a program to radare2 debug mode, most of the time I get the following error:

```
$sudo r2 -d a.out
Hello world!= attach 2851 2851
Cannot open '/proc/2851/maps': No such file or directory
Hello world!asm.bits 64
Cannot open '/proc/2851/maps': No such file or directory
-- Now i'm like an evil engineer. MUAHAHAH
[0x00000000]>
```

Radare2 works but doesn't load the program. Should I need to configure something else on the system?

This is on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

Comment: I think you should  try r2 or ubuntu support channels

Answer (score -1):

I think I had a similar issue and I got it solved by making sure that the target program has executable permissions set. Something like this in your case

```
chmod +x a.out
```

Hope that helps!